# Nothing happen when running git clone

Tags: git

I try to run git clone on my server. But this is the only thing that is happen

```
root@ns304946:/var/www/html/poklid.tk/public_html# git clone https://github.com/brusselopole/Worldopole.git
Cloning into 'Worldopole'...
```

Nothing more. What can be wrong?

Comment: Do you get back to the shell prompt or is it just stuck in the git command? In the second case I would probably guess on a network issue. Is your internet connection ok? Can you access that host/URL otherwise? Might there be a firewall or proxy which is not correctly configured and blocking the request?

Comment: Yes it say it is time out. Yes i can access the server from the internet so i dont think it is a network problem. How can i check if it can be the firewall that is blocking the request?

Comment: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/brusselopole/Worldopole.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

Comment: Please check internet connection, firewall settings... Do a ping and see if it goes smoothly...

Comment: Yes a ping works

Comment: How big is the file? Again check ping rate perhaps its on the slow side...

Comment: maybe 24 mb hard to tell. You can see for yourself here https://github.com/brusselopole/Worldopole

Comment: It has working before but suddenly it stop working.

Comment: Surely there's an error going on and just bad error handling from Git itself. Start by checking credentials and connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

It's working on my PC. Maybe you'd want to check your route and /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the protocol used from https to git:

`git clone git://github.com/brusselopole/Worldopole.git`

Answer (score 0):

You may be having proxy issues (I wouldn't know why they appeared "suddenly").

Diagnostic actions:

1. Post the output of

   ```
   $ git config --global --list
   $ git config --system --list
   $ git config --local --list
   ```

(the latter will probably not apply).

2. Try cloning another repo.
3. Check the config files for the proxy settings. Remove the settings.
4. Start git config ["from scratch"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860379/2707864), i.e., removing all config files (back them up).